# How to Extract Data From Auto Scale Group via AWS Java SDK Client

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-java-2.0

As a business requirement, we need to control AWS autoscale group policies from API calls. I have gone through the Java SDK client doc but I couldn't find any information related to API calls. I am not sure if those are feasible. Following are the requirements,

- Should be able to set the desired capacity of a particular AWS autoscale group (this is in the doc.)
- Should be able to get the desired capacity of a particular AWS autoscale group
- Should be able to get min count of a particular AWS autoscale group
- Should be able to get max count of a particular AWS autoscale group

**Set autoscale group desired capacity via Java SDK.**

```
AmazonAutoScaling client = AmazonAutoScalingClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider(CredentialProfiles.API_MANAGER.getProfile())).build();
SetDesiredCapacityRequest request = new SetDesiredCapacityRequest()
                .withAutoScalingGroupName(autoScaleGroupNameValue).withDesiredCapacity(desiredCapacityValue)
                .withHonorCooldown(true);
        SetDesiredCapacityResult response = get().setDesiredCapacity(request);
```

Please let me know if those actions can be made via AWS SDK Java client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To Set the desired capacity**

```
AmazonAutoScaling asgClient = AmazonAutoScalingClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER).build();

SetDesiredCapacityRequest dcRequest = new SetDesiredCapacityRequest()
        .withAutoScalingGroupName("AUTO_SCALING_GROUP_NAME").withDesiredCapacity(2);
SetDesiredCapacityResult dcResult = asgClient.setDesiredCapacity(dcRequest);
```

**To retrieve the ASG details**

```
DescribeAutoScalingGroupsRequest asgRequest = new DescribeAutoScalingGroupsRequest()
        .withAutoScalingGroupNames("AUTO_SCALING_GROUP_NAME");
DescribeAutoScalingGroupsResult asgResult = asgClient.describeAutoScalingGroups(asgRequest);

List<AutoScalingGroup> groupList = asgResult.getAutoScalingGroups();

groupList.forEach((asgroup) -> System.out.println(asgroup.getDesiredCapacity())); // Desired Capacity
groupList.forEach((asgroup) -> System.out.println(asgroup.getMinSize())); // Min
groupList.forEach((asgroup) -> System.out.println(asgroup.getMaxSize())); // Max
```